# Control Reaches end of non- void function

Tags: c++, function, void

basically I can't get rid of the error message coming at the very last bracket that says `"error control reaches end of non-void function"`

```
// DEFINE FUNCTION is_prime() HERE
double is_prime( int j)
{
    int  imin;
    int  imax;
    for (int j = imin; j <= imax; j++)
    {
        for ( int k=2; k<=imax; k++)
        {
            for (int x=2; x<k; x++)
            {
                if (k%x ==0)
                {
                    cout<<endl;
                }
                else
                    cout<< k ;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `return`.

Comment: `double is_prime( int j)` - this function expects you to return a value, specifically a double. You're not doing that, so the function reaches its end without having a return value. That's what the error message is saying.

Comment: You also have a host of other problems with this code - you probably want to return a `bool`, not a `double`, given the function name. You're also using `imin` and `imax` uninitialized.

Comment: Down voters - What good is it to leave a down vote without leaving a reason?.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return` statement to the bottom of your function just before the last `}` to return a floating point value. 
Also, you should initialize `imin` and `imax`.
***OR*** Given the purpose of your function, you could type it as: `BOOL is_prime( int j)` then return TRUE or FALSE, depending on whether argument passed in is prime or not.  For example:

```
BOOL is_prime(int j)
{ 
   ...
   for ( int k=2; k<=imax; k++)
   //other code
   return TRUE;//if prime
   ...  
   return FALSE; //if not prime 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by a return statement?

Comment: See my edit, Assuming you are using C/C++, when a function is prototyped non-void, it is intended that a value will be returned, and the function should be written to accommodate that. this is the basic reason for the error message you are getting. There are other problems with the function: uninitialized variables being just one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `is_prime` function is supposed to return a double value! (e.g. `return 3.0f`)

Answer (score 0):

Your function has a return type. You need to return a value.

```
// DEFINE FUNCTION is_prime() HERE
double is_prime( int j)
{
    int  imin;
    int  imax;
    for (int j = imin; j <= imax; j++)
    {
        for ( int k=2; k<=imax; k++)
        {
            for (int x=2; x<k; x++)
            {
                if (k%x ==0)
                {
                    cout<<endl;
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                    cout<< k ;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can also remove the return type, since you seem to display the results: `void is_prime(int j)`.